# Show Direction Between two location in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, direction

I am developing application to track user location. In that I need to know how to show shortest direction from one location to another in Map Activity.I should not be a straight line. It should be like a road path.

Comment: read google direction api for andriod . https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to draw a polyline between 2 points and following road, you can try with the library Google-Directions-Android

You can add the library on gradle with compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.0.7'

You can use all your point (Latlng) and use them into the waypoint method.

```
Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                .travelMode(/* Travel Mode */)
                .withListener(/* Listener that delivers routing results.*/)
                .waypoints(/*waypoints*/)
                .build();
    routing.execute();
```

actual code

```
 start = new LatLng(18.015365, -77.499382);
    waypoint= new LatLng(18.01455, -77.499333);
    end = new LatLng(18.012590, -77.500659);

    Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                .travelMode(Routing.TravelMode.WALKING)
                .withListener(this)
                .waypoints(start, waypoint, end)
                .build();
    routing.execute();
```

Comment: check updated answer.  Check the entire working sample at https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android

Comment: Thanks.. But it doesn't work for me. sample project also not working.

Comment: After several test I maked it work . Thanks @crashOveride

Comment: I discovered this library yesterday, and now, Im using it. But.. What are the limits of usage? I didn't read anything about it in github repository. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%s&daddr=%s",  "Malakwal", "Lahore");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Dear @Hamza Asif, could you post some explanation and clarification to the peace of code in your answer?

Comment: be careful in cases that Google Maps is not available, causing a `ActivityNotFoundException`